When running: git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>, file is assumed un changed but when changing branch, error appears
I have a file in my Pycharm which I have changed so the commits are shown. As soon as I run the following command thorough the CLI and try to change the active branch (via CLI or Pycharm GUI):
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

I encounter the following error:
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
...

although I have used the --assume-unchanged option, it says that there are changes but my working tree is clean.
Additionally, I have tried restarting Pycharm and also my computer, however the issue still persists. How can I fix this?

Sounds like the file is changed between HEAD and the commit that you are trying to go to..... so, you have changes in the file locally that you asked git to ignore... and there are also changes applied on the file that you do not have in your tree..... what should be the right way to handle this situation if this is the case you are into?

Thank Git, it noticed. --assume-unchanged is not an instruction, it is your promise that you will not change the file. But you did change it and break your promise. Fortunately, Git didn't believe you and warned you.

Despite the thousand tutorials that suggest to use --assume-unchanged, it cannot be used successfully to ask Git to ignore changes to tracked files.

Thanks all for the information I had no idea about this. Really helps to give context on how to use this

This issue will persist if the file f you are trying to "untrack" in your main branch, is/will cause conflicts in the other branch, in which you are attempting to checkout. So for example, you perform some changes in f, and do not want to track them, you performed a
git update-index --assume-unchanged f

Now, if you do a
git checkout other_branch

It will raise the error which you quote. This happens because --assume-unchanged is actually there to improve speeds of the git-relates processes. For files which are extremely big and may contain numerous changes, and the author feels it is better to ignore the check for changes made on this file, one should use this option.
However, for your use case, the --skip-worktree option would be correct, wherein you want to change the file, but want to ignore its changes so as to perform checkout, push, pull, merge, etc. More about this here.
Now, if you want to play it completely safe (or rather proceed primitivly), and simply want to carry forward the changes made in file f to another branch, you can make the changes and checkout to a new branch via:
git checkout -b new_branch

This way your changes in f are carried forward in the new branch. But if you still want to checkout to a branch with a deviated history from your current branch, and carry forward the changes and want to keep it simple, then simply copy them manually. However otherwise, --skip-wortree would be a nice option.
Hope this helps!

It makes complete sense thank you very much! I do have a question though about this. It is not the first time that I try to use the --assume-unchanged and before this try it has worked as intented. Why does it work sometimes and why does it not work sometimes? Does it have something to do with caching of Pycharm?
Again thanks for the answer it is suuuper clear now!

I am not sure when it worked for you and when it did not. But, I suppose it would have worked when the changes in file f would not have caused any conflicts in the other branch: maybe cause f does not exist there or maybe cause it was a new branch like I pointed (see, "primitive" solution).
I am not sure how the caching in Pycharm works since I have never used the editor.
